# How can we create a View where 2 fields in Table A both require data from a particular field in Table B?

Tags: mysql

Create a new SQL view called TripMaps that includes the station details (landmark, latitude, longitude) for both start and end stations for every TripID. (Stations.name and trips.startstation contains similar station names)

[image]

Comment: A view is just a saved `SELECT` query. So you do it the same way you would do it in an ordinary `SELECT`.

Comment: This sounds like homework. The whole point of homework is for you to figure it out based on your lesson, not get someone else to do it for you.

Comment: The issue im facing currently is, i have to join 2 tables with a particular field from Trips that joins on two of the other fields in stations (startstation and endstation). I have no idea how the table fields should be displayed. I dont need direct answers, just guidance on how the join tables can be created will be greatly appreciated @Barmar

Comment: You need to join with `STATIONS` twice, once `ON stationID = startStation` and then `ON stationID = endStation`. Give each of them a different alias, then get the station details from each alias.

Comment: It sounded like your question was about how to write a view, not how to write a query.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690562/mysql-query-show-multiple-tables-from-one-id-column/42690748#42690748 for example

Comment: Thank you. So does that mean that i will have a total of 2 sets of station details (landmark, latitude, longitude)(one set for start stn, one for end stn) for my new table?

Comment: I just started learning sql 4 weeks ago. And i really appreciate all the help here

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace view TripMaps as
select
s.Name,
s.CoordLat,
s.CoordLong,
s.Landmark
from Stations s
where s.Name in (Select t.StartStation,t.EndStation from Trips t);
```

This assumes that you're using same exact names with identical formatting for both Stations.Name and Trips.StartStation / Trips.EndStation)